# How can I get something to (really) run AfterPublish using MSBuild

Tags: svn, shell, msbuild, clickonce, csproj

I need to shell out (to call svn commit on my .application file) after a ClickOnce publish. However I've not been able to find a way to hook it into my MSBuild .csproj file.

- The PostBuild Event is too early
- And calling '***start Some.exe***' in PostBuild does not run in the background
- And using the AfterBuild Target from MSBuild is done ***before*** the files are deployed.

**Dang!**

I used the pretty cool [MSBuild SideKick](http://www.attrice.info/msbuild/) to inspect my .csproj file and when I run from inside SideKick the AfterBuild target does in fact happen after build. Hoever; my shell out fails and I'd prefer for things to work from inside the IDE anyway.

Does anyone have any pearls of wisdom in this area?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried creating an **AfterPublish** target? You should create this target in your .csproj file after the  statement.

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)

Comment: Here in the future, that target stopped working: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/26710

Answer (score 0):

We've used the  task to shell out at different points in the build.  This spawns a new instance of cmd.exe for you.  I've used this to spawn PowerShell scripts in the background.  It's nice since you can do a lot with PowerShell, just be sure to use stdout so the PS log shows up in your team build.